# vboxweb failed at boot and can't start

Tags: virtualbox

Groovy Gorilla

```
● vboxweb.service - VirtualBox Web Service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/vboxweb.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2021-02-14 13:23:27 EST; 12min ago
    Process: 13030 ExecStart=/usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxweb-service.sh start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 14 13:23:26 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: Starting VirtualBox Web Service...
Feb 14 13:23:27 zika.gattaca.net vboxweb-service.sh[13030]: vboxweb-service.sh: Starting VirtualBox web service.
Feb 14 13:23:27 zika.gattaca.net vboxweb-service.sh[13030]: vboxweb-service.sh: failed: VirtualBox web service failed to start.
Feb 14 13:23:27 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: vboxweb.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 14 13:23:27 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: vboxweb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 14 13:23:27 zika.gattaca.net systemd[1]: Failed to start VirtualBox Web Service.
```

add to /etc/default/virtualbox:

```
VBOXWEB_USER=brad
VBOXWEB_GROUP=vboxusers
```

and worked but failed again after reboot.

the service is disabled until a solution is found

modprobe vboxdrv is not complaining

and

```
modinfo vboxdrv
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-31-generic/updates/dkms/vboxdrv.ko
version:        6.1.16_Ubuntu r140961 (0x00300000)
license:        GPL
description:    Oracle VM VirtualBox Support Driver
author:         Oracle Corporation
srcversion:     CB64A31463F675E2949EA48
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
name:           vboxdrv
vermagic:       5.8.0-31-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           force_async_tsc:force the asynchronous TSC mode (int)

reinstalled DKMS
DKMS: uninstall completed.
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 6.1.16
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.10.1) over (6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.10.1) ...
Setting up virtualbox-ext-pack (6.1.16-1~ubuntu1.20.10.1) ...
virtualbox-ext-pack: downloading: http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.16/Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.16.vbox-extp
ack
The file will be downloaded into /usr/share/virtualbox-ext-pack
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.16.vbox-extpack: expected 9802482b77b95a954cb5111793da10d009009a4e9a9c4eaa4bd1ae5
dafe9db46, removing the file.
dpkg: error processing package virtualbox-ext-pack (--configure):
 installed virtualbox-ext-pack package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (6.1.16-dfsg-6~ubuntu1.20.10.1) ...
Loading new virtualbox-6.1.16 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-31-generic 5.8.0-44-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-31-generic
Done.


DKMS: install completed.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 virtualbox-ext-pack
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What is this trying to tell me :

```
Hash mismatch Oracle_VM_VirtualBox_Extension_Pack-6.1.16.vbox-extpack: expected 9802482b77b95a954cb5111793da10d009009a4e9a9c4eaa4bd1ae5
dafe9db46, removing the file.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Complete Instructions for a new installing without uninstalling from the old box.
https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

note: After clean uninstall you should reboot the system to load the kernel-module on a new, and while uninstall all drivers and services from vm should stopped.

The number self mismatched because the said problem - non equivalence - maybe with the newer versions your bug is gone, or maybe not all old services was unload while installation!

Comment: Complete Environment under http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.18/

Comment: Thanks but I have 20.10 Groovy Gorilla. Oracle has 20.04.